# Strange Summation in calculus

Tags: integration, limits, summation

I have a assignment in calculus 1 to do and it has a problem involving a limit and a sum, but I have no idea how to do it. This is the problem:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n\left(\frac1{2n+1}+\frac1{2n+3}+\ldots+\frac1{4n-1}\right)\right)\,.$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Note that $$4n-1=(2n+1)+(2n-2)=(2n+1)+2(n-1)\,,$$ so there are $n$ fractions in the expression. The largest is $\frac1{2n+1}$, and the smallest is $\frac1{4n-1}$, so

$$\frac14<\frac{n}{4n-1}\le\frac1{2n+1}+\ldots+\frac1{4n-1}\le\frac{n}{2n+1}<\frac12\,.$$

Now multiply by $n$ and think about what happens as $n$ increases.